# Get element or default value?

Tags: .net, linq

Is there a solution in linq to get an element from an array and if it is out of range return a default value?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var arr = new int[] { 5, 4, 8 };
    //Console.WriteLine("{0}", arr[5] ?? 6);
    //nah Console.WriteLine("{0}", arr.GetElementOrNull(5) ?? 6);
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", arr.GetElementOrValue(5, 6));
}
```

Comment: When would you want the default instead of the value? And since these are value-types, why? It's unclear.

Comment: Yes, that's better. You should avoid needing this though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you just want the default value (null, zero, etc) then you can use the built-in [`ElementAtOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb494386.aspx):

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}", arr.ElementAtOrDefault(5));
```

But if you want to specify your own "default" value (eg, 6) then you'll need to provide your own extension method to do it:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}", arr.ElementAtOrValue(5, 6));

public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static T ElementAtOrValue<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> source, int index, T defaultValue)
    {
        if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        if (index >= 0)
        {
            var list = source as IList<T>;
            if (list != null)
            {
                if (index < list.Count) return list[index];
            }
            else
            {
                using (var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
                {
                    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
                    {
                        if (index-- == 0) return enumerator.Current;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return defaultValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: I wanted to specify the default value (6 in my sample) when it is out of range (5 which is correct) but I think I can make default work since I don't really need it to be '6'. Null and non int `.Min()` should work

Comment: Does `[]` work on IList? good code but I wanted to avoid writing extensions I should copy/paste into every project. I suppose this IS the best solution. Accepted

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use `FirstOrDefault()` in your LINQ query.

More here: [Official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/bb340482)